# Octopus deploy JSON Variable substitution not working as expected

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am new to Octopus Deploy.

In my .net core applicaton appsettings.json, i have the following variable:

```
{
"protectedResourceMap": []
}
```

I have a Octopus variable definition for this variable and values is like. Other variables exists which is used here.

```
["#{ApiPath}"]
```

But the final output i am getting is an empty array:

```
{
"protectedResourceMap": [],
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's the name of your variable? Is it "protectedResourceMap"?

Is "protectedResourceMap" in the root of your appsettings.json?

Did you enable the JSON Configuration Variables feature in your deployment step and provide the path to the file?

[image: Enabled features]